# How can I get camera position in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, api, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to know the location of the camera on a 3d map with pitch set.

The center on the map can be got by *map.getCenter();*. But when you're moving on a 3D map, focus point isn't enough to know where you are. I want to get it with longitude and latitude.
Thank you.

image↓

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeCamera Api will get you the position of the camera in webmercator coordinates, which can be easily converted into lng/lat:

```
  const camera = map.getFreeCameraOptions();

  const cameraPosition = camera._position.toLngLat();
```

I have a codepen here that shows this, getting the camera position whenever the map is moved and showing it as a circle marker on an inset map:

https://codepen.io/chriswhong/pen/RwyazBm

Comment: That's a really nice little demo!